# Getting error when trying to display points from GeoJSON in Leaflet 0.7.7

Tags: leaflet, geojson, point

I tried to display the point from GeoJSON but there is an error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)

This is my source code:

```
maps.setView(new L.LatLng(-8.203824, 113.175476), 12);

    L.geoJson(dataPelanggan, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            console.log(feature)
            return L.marker(latlng, {
                icon: L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'asset/img/marker.png',
                    iconSize: [38, 45]
                })
            });
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popUp) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popUp);
            }
        }
    }).addTo(maps);
```

i'm using leaflet version 0.7.7 because there is some kind of source code algorithm that I use using that version, then I want to add this point to clarify the function of the feature that I created. can someone help me? sorry if my sentence is confusing.

**geojson got from api...**

```
var dataPelanggan=[
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "jenis": "Pelanggan",
        "nosambungan": "519",
        "nama": "CHU",
        "alamat_pelanggan": "TEMPEH LOR",
        "Stan": "96",
        "popUp": "No. Sambungan : 519<br>Nama : CHU<br>Alamat : TEMPEH LOR<br>Stan : 96"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            "113.177157376778350",
            "-8.196966314315622"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "jenis": "Pelanggan",
        "nosambungan": "5110",
        "nama": "NUR",
        "alamat_pelanggan": "TEMPEH",
        "Stan": "125",
        "popUp": "No. Sambungan : 5110<br>Nama : NURY<br>Alamat : RAYA TEMPEH LOR<br>Stan : 125"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            "113.177076511097520",
            "-8.197180194910073"
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: It works for me with the above data and vanilla Leaflet 0.7.7, so there must be some error in your complete data or data is not available yet at the time you are trying to use it.

Comment: but this is already visible when i see it on console @TomazicM

Comment: @TomazicM or because the data too much? there are about 1000 data

Comment: No, that's not a big number. How do you actually get/load the data: through static GeoJSON variable in code or some API? If it's API, please edit your question and include relevant code.

Comment: I've found the answer, it turns out that some data in the coordinate column is null @TomazicM thank you so much for ur attention to my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that some data in the coordinate column is null. It causes the error mentioned above.